# Google Polymer <google-map-search> location and radius for search results are ignored

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to set a marker to a specific address and show nearby restaurants within a radius of 500m. The marker and the restaurants are shown but the radius is ignored. I alwas get 20 restaurant results. I was also thinking about to rank by distance and reduce the number of elements but coundn't get it working.

```
<div slot="content"
            title="">
            <div class="title">[[title]]</div>

            <google-map-search id="gps"
                               map="[[map]]"
                               query="[[mapQuery]]"
                               results="{{results}}">
            </google-map-search>

            <google-map-search id="restaurantID"
                               map="[[map]]"
                               query="[[mapQuery]]"
                               location="[[location]]"
                               radius="[[radius]]"
                               types="[[types]]"
                               results="{{restaurantResults}}">

            </google-map-search>

            <div class="map">
                <google-map map="{{map}}"
                            id="map"
                            fit-to-markers
                            longitude="[[longitude]]"
                            latitude="[[latitude]]"
                            api-key="[[googleMapApiKey]]"
                            disable-map-type-control
                            disable-street-view-control
                            singleInfoWindow
                            styles="[[mapStyles]]">

                    <template is="dom-repeat"
                              items="{{results}}"
                              as="marker">
                        <google-map-marker latitude="{{marker.latitude}}"
                                           longitude="{{marker.longitude}}"
                                           label="A">   
                            <h2>{{marker.name}}</h2>
                            <span>{{marker.formatted_address}}</span>
                        </google-map-marker>
                    </template>

                    <template is="dom-repeat"
                              items="{{restaurantResults}}"
                              as="marker">
                        <google-map-marker latitude="{{marker.latitude}}"
                                           longitude="{{marker.longitude}}"
                                           label="B"> 
                            <h2>{{marker.name}}</h2>
                            <span>{{marker.formatted_address}}</span>
                        </google-map-marker>
                    </template>

                </google-map>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and my Properties are

```
static get properties() {
            return {
                title: {
                    type: String
                },
                fields: {
                    type: Array,
                    value: ["str", "plz"]
                },
                googleMapApiKey: {
                    type: String,
                    observer: '_googleMapAPIkeyChanged'
                },
                mapQuery: {
                    type: String
                },
                location: {
                    type: Object,
                    //readOnly: true
                },
                radius: {
                    type: Number,
                    value: "500"
                },
                types: {
                    type: String,
                    value: "restaurant"
                },
            };
        }
```

Later on I set this.location = {lat: my_lat, lng: my_lng}.
But location and radius are ignored. The results are only dependent on the given mapQuery.
I think the reason for that is that the search() function of  is a textSearch() but in this case I would need a nearbysearch().

When I use https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=my_lat,my_lng&radius=500&types=restaurant&key="my_key" I get the results I need (in my case 8).
But with textsearch instead of nearby search I get 20 elements and some of them are outside my 500m radius.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. I renamed the markers items to restaurantResultsView. This way I could filter the original restaurantResults.